# How to change value inside a .dac file in python

Tags: python, file

I have a .dac file

```
   #| step | Channel| Mode | Duration|Freq.| Amplitude | Phase| 
       0       1       AWG     Pi/2    100     2           1                           
      100      0       REC     Pi/2     150     1           1
```

How do I replace the value of Pi as 180 after reading the file ?

Comment: did you check `str.replace()`?

Comment: If you read it as  a string in variable data then you can do, `data.replace('Pi', '180')`

Comment: No im reading that as an int